# How to deploy VS2008 express desktop project?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, deployment, installation, desktop-application, visual-studio-express

i was wondering how could i deploy/make it into an installer for an app which is created using vs 2008 express. i know that the setup and deployment feature is only available via the full version of visual studio right?

So are there any add ons or perhaps additional free/or non-free if it has to come to that which i can use to do this?

or is the best tool for the job is the old visual studio installer from the vs 6.0 days? :)

thanks

**Updates**:
After some googling, i found [this link on using click once to deploy vs 2008 express with tutorials in them](http://blogs.msdn.com/vbteam/archive/2008/10/02/looking-for-setup-and-deployment-project-templates.aspx), i'll check it out, but of course more & better recommendation is always welcomed :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[WiX is excellent.](http://wix.sourceforge.net/)  Here is a [good MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163456.aspx) on it too.

Answer (score 2):

I would definitely recommend ClickOnce. It's how I distribute [Comicster](http://comicster.net) (my own hobby project written using C# Express). It handles updates to your app, too, which is very nice.

If you can't deploy to a web site, ClickOnce also supports deploying to a folder for file-based installs (eg CD or network share).

Comment: I've included a link to the Comicster site in case you want to check it out. It's free, so I don't consider this spam. If anyone objects, let me know and I will remove the link.

Comment: hi Matt, is this clickonce only available in the full version of visual studio 2005? or how do i get it? thanks & my bad if this sounds really dumb :P

Comment: No, ClickOnce is available in Express. You just right-click on your project and select "Publish" to step through the deployment wizard (or bring up your project's properties and have a look at the "Publish" tab).

Comment: mm, weird as i just installed the vs 2008 C# express, maybe i have to download the whole vs 2008 express iso and download that one. thanks, spare me a lot of unnecessary googling :)

Comment: Yea, it would seems that the publish option is only available from the vs 2008 express that i installed from the iso and not just from the 2MB installer which download the rest of the setup files. weird :s

Comment: Do you get the Publish tab in the project properties?